# No Python at '"C:\Users\${USER}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe'

Tags: python, jenkins, automation, pytest, cicd

I am trying to integrate my python pytest automation framework with Jenkins to run automatically through Jenkins. I am trying to create a simple shell script using the Shining Panda Plugin and Pyenv Pipeline plugin. Here are the steps I took:

1. Created a freestyle project
2. Attached the git repository under the Source Code Management section
3. Setup a build trigger to Poll SCM every minute to see if there are changes
4. Under Build Steps, selected Custom Python Builder, set Home to C:\Users${USER}\python-workspace\selenium-python-project\venv\ , set Nature to Shell, and entered this command:

python -m pytest "C:\Users${USER}\python-workspace\selenium-python-project\Tests"

After doing all of this and running the build manually by click Build Now, I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\sa\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\pytest-automation-local>python -m pytest "C:\Users\${USER}\python-workspace\selenium-python-project\Tests" 

No Python at '"C:\Users\${USER}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe'
```

Context: Python is installed locally along with pytest and multiple dependencies. Running this same command in VSCode works fine and the automation suite runs as expected. Jenkins is also installed locally and running on localhost:8080.

Please let me know if you can help, and thank you for your time!

Further Context: I tried setting up the global environment variables in Jenkins to read the local path to where Python was located but it did not solve the problem. changing the command from "python -m pytest ... " to "pytest ..." simply threw an error saying "pytest not recognized as a commandlet"